# javascript delete not working rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

i have a partial am rendering which works well when am creating through javascript but deleting it via javascript is not working , maybe there is something am doing wrong but ma code is thus ...

the partial rendering

```
 <ul id="<%= dom_id(feed) %>">
        <%= render :partial => feed.talks %>
  </ul>
```

the partial

```
<ul class="unstyled custumer_say" style="list-style: none;">
      <li class="clearfix" style="list-style: none;">
        <%= link_to image_tag(talk.user.image.url(:tiny)),talk.user,:style=> "width: 7%; padding-right: 0px;", :class=> "pull-left img_client"%>    <div class="entry-content">

        <header>
          <strong><%= link_to talk.user.username, talk.user %>:</strong> <%= talk.details %></i><br>
          <small><i class="muted" style="font-size: 9px;"><%="#{time_ago_in_words(talk.created_at)} ago "%></i></small>

          <% if current_user.id == talk.user_id %>
          <%= link_to "x", talk, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" },remote: true, class: 'pull-right' %>

          <% end %>
                  </header>
      </div>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- End Testimonaila list-->

    <hr>
```

create.js.erb   which works fine

```
$('.feed #<%= dom_id(@feed) %>').html("<%= j render(@feed.talks) %>");
$("#new_talk")[0].reset();
```

destroy.js.erb which doesnt delete unless a full page relod

```
$('.unstyled custumer_say_<%= @talk.id %>').remove();
```

seems there is something am not doing right

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.unstyled custumer_say_<%= @talk.id %>').remove();
```

You're calling something that doesn't exist as far as I can see

Change your ul to this:

```
<ul id="unstyled custumer_say_<%= @talk.id %>" class="unstyled custumer_say" style="list-style: none;">
```

And the destroy.js.erb to

```
$("#unstyled custumer_say_<%= @talk.id %>").remove();
```

Notice the double quotes

Comment: typo its destroy.js.erb i meant